# onActivityResult is not called after process is killed

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I have a main activity (Main) and another activity (Sub) that is called from Main by

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, SubActivity.class), 25);
```

When I'm at Sub, and I kill the process (using a task manager or by `adb shell kill <pid>`), and I re-open the application, I'm taken immediately to Sub.

In Sub I have this code to call back to the Main activity:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

I would have received the requestCode (25), the resultCode (RESULT_OK) and the data on `onActivityResult` if I didn't kill the process. However in this case I'm taken to the Main activity, but the `onActivityResult`  is not called.

Is this how Android works (which I don't expect), or is there something wrong with my approach?

---

Update: This happened on my Nexus One, CyanogenMod 7.0.2, Android 2.3.3. I tried using emulator API 10, Android 2.3.4 and it worked as expected, `onActivityResult` is still called after I killed the process.

Comment: What do you mean "However in this case I'm taken to the Main activity, but the onActivityResult is not called" what IS called then?

Comment: If the process has been killed, the onActivityResult of the Main activity is not called. The onCreate, onStart, etc of the Main activity are still called as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is not why `onActivityResult` is not called, but why when you kill your app second is still alive. Did you put Toast messages in the lifecycle methods of Main and Sub, just to check which methods are called?

Comment: No. I know that after the process is killed, Android will start the last activity that was running before the process is killed. And yes, I write logs to check whether the onActivityResult is called.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and I solved it replacing the startActivityForResult functionality storing the result into the shared preferences and loading them later in onResume. Here's [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16846526/2436683) to the full solution.